# Id inheritance in JPA

Tags: java, inheritance, jpa

I have the following Scheme

```
@Entity
public class A

{
@Id
String field1
String field2
}
public class B extends A
{
 String field3;
 @OneToMany(MappedBy="b")
 List<C> cList;
}

public class C extends A
{
String field4;
@ManyToOne
B b;
}
```

Both class B and C extends A and get their id From A using table per concrete class strategy but the problem is that class B has one to many relationship with class C so what i want is to change the id of class C to be a composite key consist of the inherited id field1 and  the id of the object b. That will allow two different object of b to have the two different object of c with the same field1 value.
Is what i am thinking possible (override inheritance) i am using eclipse link as persistence provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, having different Id types in an entity hierarchy is not supported by the JPA inheritance strategies as it introduces ambiguities.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216771/is-there-a-way-to-override-id-in-an-entitys-subclass-in-jpa) for details.

to work around this limitation you could:

- 'detach' `C` from the hierarchy so that it does not derive from `A`
- use `C` as an attribute in a different entity

Comment: But there is a common functionality that can be done by B, C . and i have queries that return both B and C.

Comment: Doing that will add overhead in management of these two object(make two find, two persist, two query....)

Comment: @user3041392 - yes, it is a technical limitation with no pretty solution I'm afraid. sorry. Object hierarchies and RDBMS don't always play nice.

Comment: thanks @kostja  , is it possible to make B extends C and b has many C at the same time.

Comment: @user3041392 - yes, relationships among entities in same hierarchy are legal. You can use them just like a regular relationship.